# call a service layer function in Listener class on Session destroyed in Spring

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, session, listener

I have one listener configured in web.xml

```
<listener>
      <listener-class>com.Mylistener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

**MyListener.java**

has following code

```
 public class MyListener extends HttpSessionEventPublisher{

           myServiceInterface myService;

           @Override
           public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {     
              super.sessionCreated(event);
           }

           @Override
           public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
             //Call a method from service layer which is communicating with DAO layer and then database.
    super.sessionDestroyed(event);
           }

    }
```

That service already had its own mapping and working fine.

what other mappings, i need to do to call service layer in Mylistener, above code it not working at all

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: yes, if i am using it directly then then it is throwing NULLPOINTER Exception while calling DAO layer because we are not instantiating DAO object anywhere. Generally we do it in XML files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MyListener extends HttpSessionEventPublisher {
    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(final HttpSessionEvent event) {
        final ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(event.getSession().getServletContext());
        final MyServiceInterface service = ctx.getBean(MyServiceInterface.class);
        // use service
        super.sessionDestroyed(event);
    }
}
```

Should work (not tested).

Comment: final ApplicationContext ctx = this.getContext(event.getSession().getServletContext()); this line is throwing compilation error "The method getContext(ServletContext) from the type HttpSessionEventPublisher is not visible".

Comment: Right, package protected, sorry; You can just do the same in your child class (I mean copy the method body). I updated my answer.